# LineChartData without x values on constructor Charts Swift 3

Tags: swift, charts, swift3, core-graphics

I’m using iOS Charts.framework (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my swift 3.0 xcodeproject.

I know that "All dataset constructors have changed - they do not take an array of x-indices anymore" but how do I put strings on my x axis now if LineChartData doesn't have a "xVals" parameters anymore???
Before was so easy to do that...

```
let weights: [Double] = self.getWeigths()
let weightDates: [String] = self.getWeightDates()

var yValues : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0 ..< dateLastWeights.count {
        let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: weights[i])
        yValues.append(entry)
    }
let set: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yValues, label: "First Set")
var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
dataSets.append(set)

let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: weightDates, dataSets: dataSets)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 3.0.1 version, you can also do:

```
lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels)
lineChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying lots of things and discussing with others developers we made it!

```
self.lineChart.xAxis.granularity = 1
self.lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: { (index, _) -> String in
        return self.dateLastWeights[Int(index)]
    })
```